# In ASP.NET MVC what are the differences between "<%=", "<%:" "<%#"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms-view-engine

I've tried to perform a search on the above query but probably due to the angle brackets, I didn't find anything on the matter.

Could anyone please explain what the differences are between `<%=`,  `<%:` `<%#`?

I seem to recall that `<%#` is preferred over `<%=` but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [article](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx) describes them pretty well.

- `<%=`: Rendering Code Syntax
- `<%: %>`: [HTML encoded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) renedring (same usage as `<%=`)
- `<%# %>`: Data Binding Syntax - works with server side controls in classic WebForms applications, inapplicable in MVC

Comment: thank you. I'm a bit surprised about the <%# because I believe that I picked up the latter in an MVC tutorial on the asp.net site. :S

Answer (score 3):

`<%= xxx %>` Inserts the text in xxx into the page at that location. ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx))

`<%: xxx %>` Same as above except it html encodes the text for your convenience - (Except if xxx is an HtmlString which indicates it is already encoded)

`<%# xxx %>` Same as the first one too except xxx is only evaluated when DataBind() is called on the form (not really applicable in MVC) ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx))

Martin

Comment: Excellent answer which is pretty much what Darin wrote. I marked his reply as the answer because the link he provided taught me something new i.e. <%$